# How decode BLE characteristic value?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

In `didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor`, I call `peripheral.readValue( for: characteristic)`.

In `didUpdateValueFor`, I read characteristic value and output is 1bytes.

So I use bytes to string.

```
var str = String( data: characteristic.value! , encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String!
```

Output is:

> Optional("\u{02}").

I want to get "02". How should I do this?

Comment: `as String!` ??? Thats so ugly. Use `if let`, `if var` or provide a default value using the nil coalescing operator `?? ""`. Btw `String.Encoding` is redundant and don't force unwrap your data value.

Comment: I don't know what is your goal but if you just want to convert your byte to string  `String(format: "%02d", characteristic.value!.first!)` and make sure to safely unwrap the first byte of your data

Comment: Ok, thanks your suggestion. I know how should I do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your CBCharacteristic object directly to this function which you have received in your **didUpdateValueFor** function. you will have your an 8-bit value from this.

```
private func myCharacteristics(from characteristic: CBCharacteristic) -> String {

  guard let characteristicData = characteristic.value,
  let byte = characteristicData.first else { return "Error" }

 switch byte {
  case 0: return "0th bit"
  case 1: return "1st bit"
  case 2: return "2nd bit"
  case 3: return "3rd bit"
  case 4: return "4th bit"
  case 5: return "5th bit"
  case 6: return "6th bit"
  default:
  return "Other"
 }
}

I hope this will help you.
```